Qt Tool qmllint not working on imported C++ modules
I want to use qmllint on my Main.qml, which uses modules exposed from C++ side, such as the mainCtrls import and the mainControls keyword:
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.15

// My C++ module import
import mainCtrls 1.0

Window {
    id: root
    title: mainControls.version
    visible: true

    // more code...
}

The linter shows the following warnings:
Warning: Main.qml:4:1: Warnings occurred while importing module "mainCtrls": [import]
import mainCtrls
^^^^^^
---
Warning: Failed to import mainCtrls. Are your import paths set up properly? [import]
---

Warning: Main.qml:19:12: Unqualified access [unqualified]
    title: mainControls.version
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
Warning: Main.qml:19:12: Could not compile binding for title: Cannot access value for name mainControls [compiler]
    title: mainControls.version

the mainCtrls module is a C++ class which is exposed in main.cpp using qmlRegisterType. The mainControls keyword can be used in QML due to setting a ContextProperty to the MainControlsModel class in my main.cpp:
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // ... some code ...

    qmlRegisterType<MainControlsModel>("mainCtrls", 1, 0, "MainModel");

    MainControlsModel mainControls;

    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("mainControls", &mainControls);

    // ... some more code ...

QObject::connect(
        &engine,
        &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreationFailed,
        &app,
        []() { QCoreApplication::exit(-1); },
        Qt::QueuedConnection);

    engine.loadFromModule("G6_GUIApp", "Main"); 

    // Start thread and Qt event loop (for frontend).
    backendThread.start();
    auto result = app.exec();

    // Thread clean up
    backendThread.quit();
    backendThread.wait();
    return result;
}

I know that the qmllint tool may not be able to statically link to the C++ module, hence, I have written a qmldir file and placed it into the directory, where my Main.qml lives:
// qmldir
module mainCtrls
typeinfo mainCtrls.qmltypes
classname MainModel

Additionally, I wrote a mainCtrls.qmltypes file and placed it in the same directory as the qmldir and Main.qml file:
[
    {
        "version": 1.0,
        "module": "mainCtrls",
        "name": "MainModel",
        "className": "MainControlsModel",
        "properties": [
            { // ...
            }
         ],
         "methods": [
            { // ...
            } 
         ],
         "signals": [
            { // ...
            }
         ],
    }
]

My CMakeLists.txt file includes the QML and source files:
qt_add_executable(My_GUIApp 
    src/main.cpp
    resources.qrc
)

qt_add_qml_module(My_GUIApp
    URI My_GUIApp
    VERSION 1.0

    SOURCES
        src/main.cpp 
        src/maincontrolsmodel.h src/maincontrolsmodel.cpp
        # more cpp files

    QML_FILES
        content/Main.qml
        # more QML files


    RESOURCES
        content/qmldir
        # more resources like svg's
)

My qmllint version is 6.6.2. I run the qmllint tool from commandline inside the directory, where qmldir, qmltypes and Main.qml live:
$ qmllint -i qmldir --dry-run Main.qml
What can I do to make it possible for qmllint to be aware of the C++ modules during static code analysis?
